# Start Bar Shows Up Over Maximized Form (Pocket PC 2003)

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework, .net-1.1, pocketpc

### Environment

- Windows XP SP3 x32
- Visual Studio 2005 Standard
- Windows Mobile/Pocket PC 2003
- .NET Compact Framework 1.0 SP3 and .NET Framework 1.1
- Honeywell Dolphin 9500 Handheld Barcode Scanner

### Goal

I have a three form application and an external class (Program.cs) that has the application entry point, `Main()`.  The main form loads first and then, from within `MainForm_Load(...)`, instantiates/shows a new form kind of like a splash screen.  I want all three forms to be maximized. All three forms have the following properties set:

- `this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;`
- `this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;`
- `this.ControlBox = false;`

### Problem

The "splash screen" form shows up full screen without any issue.  I then dispose of it and show the main screen (first to load and the param for `Application.Run();`.  From the main screen, once a list box SelectedIndexChanged event is detected, a third form is shown (leaving the main form behind said third form).  That third form shows the task bar *over* the top portion of my form: [image: image here]
Upon closing this form, the main form now has the task bar overlayed as well.

### Code

Friend paste links.  Let me know if I should just post the code here.  WorkOrderView is over a thousand lines so I figured this would be easier.

- ["Main" Form (WorkOrders.cs)](http://friendpaste.com/5Sp743sEUGC5Lex512uOUg)
- ["Third" Form (WorkOrderView.cs)](http://friendpaste.com/5NJWfIvVRerXJj8zBbz2iN) - Pictured above

### Unrelated Suggestions

I am quite a green programmer and I especially lack experience in this environment.  So, if you have any suggestions/criticisms on the way I'm doing some things, don't hesitate to hit me with them.  Probably best to just comment on the post instead of posting an answer for those types of replies.

### Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I only run Windows Mobile 5 (WM5) these days. (I got to move up from PocketPC 2003 a couple of years ago. LOL)

I've found that defining a Form's Window Size does not work well on mobile devices, and that showing/hiding multiple forms is awkward and never behaves the way you want.

Still, make sure your Main Form has it's `WindowState` set to **Maximized**.

I also set `ControlBox` and `MinimizeBox` to **False**, if that helps.

Instead of using multiple forms, it will look much nicer if you simply use Panels as your forms with the Main Form as some kind of MDI container (bad choice of words, but that is what I'm doing).

In my **Designer View**, each panel is just a small box full of controls.

- To work with each panel, select it in the *Visual Studio* designer, and you will see a position box (arrows up & down and left & right).
- Right-Click the position box and click *Bring to Front*.
- Now go over to the panel control's Properties and set `Dock` to **Fill**.
- While this panel is full screen, add all of your buttons, textboxes, etc. with appropriate names. Names like `pnl1_button1` and `pnl2_button1` are easier to understand in your code than the VS default `button1` and `button2`.
- When you are through with your design view of this panel, go back to the `Dock` properties and set it back to **None**.
- Go on to the next panel control.

I have found it also helps to maintain a small sketch of your panels with their names and the names of their controls.

In the `Load` event of your main form, set every `Panel`'s `Dock` property to **DockStyle.Fill**. Then, as you want to show one form, simply call `Panel1.BringToFront()` instead of `dialog.Show()`.

Mobile development isn't hard, but it is different. :)

**EDIT:**

In the project's *Program.cs* file, I keep the following static tools that I can use to turn ON and OFF the Start Menu (doesn't work so well in WM5, but I've still got it in my code from my PocketPC version).

I have not had to open this project in a year or so, but it should all be valid. Give them a try. If I've left something out, just let me know.

Once this is pasted into your project's *Program.cs* file, just call `Program.ShowWindowsMenu(false);` when your program starts and `Program.ShowWindowsMenu(true);` when your program exits.

```
static IntPtr _taskBar;
static IntPtr _sipButton;

public enum Notify_Events {
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_NONE = 0,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_TIME_CHANGE = 1,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_SYNC_END = 2,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_DEVICE_CHANGE = 7,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_RS232_DETECTED = 9,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_RESTORE_END = 10,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_WAKEUP = 11,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_TZ_CHANGE = 12,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_OFF_AC_POWER,
  NOTIFICATION_EVENT_ON_AC_POWER
}

public enum WindowPosition {
  SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,
  SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040
}

[DllImport("coredll.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindowW", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowCE(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int x, int y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

static void ShowWindowsMenu(bool enable) {
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) {
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _taskBar = FindWindowCE("HHTaskBar", null); // Find the handle to the Start Bar
      if (_taskBar != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_taskBar, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show Start" : "Hide Start", err);
  }
  try {
    if (enable) {
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 240, 26, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // display the start bar
      }
    } else {
      _sipButton = FindWindowCE("MS_SIPBUTTON", "MS_SIPBUTTON");
      if (_sipButton != IntPtr.Zero) { // If the handle is found then hide the start bar
        SetWindowPos(_sipButton, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0, 0, 0, (int)WindowPosition.SWP_HIDEWINDOW); // Hide the start bar
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    ErrorWrapper(enable ? "Show SIP" : "Hide SIP", err);
  }
}

static void ErrorWrapper(string routine, Exception e) {
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Message)) {
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, routine, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.None, 0);
  }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Declare a private static instance of your main form, then wrap that in a try....catch routine inside your project's `Program.cs` file like so:

```
static Form1 ppcForm = null;

static void Main() {
  ShowWindowsMenu(false);
  try {
    ppcForm = new Form1();
    Application.Run(ppcForm );
  } catch (Exception err) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(err.Message)) {
      ErrorWrapper("Mobile Form (Program)", err);
    }
  } finally {
    ShowWindowsMenu(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have those three properties defined and the Forms sometimes abide  and sometimes do not...it's fascinatingly infuriating. Someone suggested I use panels in a previous question to SO, however I am not prepared to go down that route at this point.  If I cannot find a solution to this problem, I will of course be forced to, but for now I am going to stick with separate forms. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Hey Eric, I added some code for you. Though not exactly what you're after, it should be able to Show and Hide the Start Menu.

Comment: Much appreciated!  I am trying to compile and I get an error on MarshalAs (The type or namespace name could not be found).  I already have using System.Runtime.InteropServices; and mscorlib is in my references.  Is this something missing from .NET 1.1 or .NET CF 1.0 SP3?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hmmm... Honestly? I don't even know what the purpose of `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]` is. Have you tried commenting that line out? Your code may run fine without it. Or! Maybe let `SetWindowPos` return an Object that you can then cast to whatever. I don't even use the return value in my code.

Comment: That worked!  Thanks!  When the application closes in an unexpected manner, the start bar is missing.  Is there any way to catch the be-all-end-all close or exception so that I can add some kind of "finally" block to it and show the start bar again?

Comment: Sorry. I got busy. Yes, there is, though! See EDIT2 above (as soon as I get that written in there....)

Comment: Once again, much appreciated!  I wish I could upvote your more than once haha.  Thanks for being so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you're after is usually referred to as "kiosk mode" (which may help your search engine results).

The underlying issue is that the start bar is not part of your app - it's part of the Shell app and you're competing with it for desired behavior.  What you want is something the Platform is trying to prevent you from doing, so you have to be prepared to put your developer boot on the platform's neck to get it to behave.

[This blog entry](http://www.satter.org/2007/04/kiosk_pattern.html) is a really good starting point for this issue and will probably give you what you need, but feel free to use a search engine to find more/aternate proposals. There's actually a lot of material on the web for this - more than would belong in this answer.

Comment: I was interpreting an MSDN article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxz0e21k.aspx) as saying that a "full sized" form was a "maximized" form and was supported behavior.  I have not had problems with most of the forms I have maximized, which is why this is so puzzling.  I will look into Kiosk mode.  Thanks for your reply!